# Simple Program that Implements a Multi-thread Example from a Tutorial Runs Slower than Single Threaded Implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading

I tried following the first example from the tutorial here -> [YouTube Link](https://youtu.be/zUy66Bats5c?t=981).

The code for the example is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>


unsigned long long OddSum = 0;
unsigned long long EvenSum = 0;

void findEven(unsigned long long start, unsigned long long end){
    for (unsigned long long i = start; i <= end; i++){
        if((i & 1)==0){
            EvenSum += i;
        }
    }
}


void findOdd(unsigned long long start, unsigned long long end){
    for (unsigned long long i = start; i <= end; i++){
        if((i & 1)==1){
            OddSum += i;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    unsigned long long start = 0, end = 1900000000;

    auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::thread t1(findEven, start, end);
    std::thread t2(findOdd, start, end);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    // findOdd(start, end);
    // findEven(start, end);


    auto stopTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stopTime - startTime);

    std::cout << "OddSum : " << OddSum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "EvenSum : " << EvenSum << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Sec : " << duration.count()/1000000 << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

When I run the single thread version it takes 3 seconds in total but the multithread version takes 18 seconds. I'm not sure what's wrong. Other posts have mentioned that threads are useless on a single core machine but I'm running on a multi-core CPU. Is there something obvious I'm overlooking? Thank you!

Tried the solution as shown in the tutorial and was expecting the multi-threaded version to be faster than the single thread implementation. The actual outcome was that the multi-threaded version took longer.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled?  If not, then any performance measurements you take are essentially invalid.

Comment: Threads are not free to use, they have overhead.  They take time to create and start. 
Also this code doesn't even use threads to run faster it just shows you how to start and join with them. Actually multithreading code would split the loops into smaller parts and assign those to threads.

Comment: @MilesBudnek That was it. I turned of debugging mode and it did it in half the time.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem: Cache coherence

The reason the threaded program runs more slowly than the
sequential program is the cost of the
[cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence)
protocol.

In a multi-core CPU, each core has its own
[Level 1 (L1) Cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache), which is
fast storage that the core attempts to use to satisfy memory reads and
writes.  Memory accesses that miss the L1 cache have to go to a slower
resource such as L2 or L3, or even main memory, although on a typical
multi-core CPU, at least
[L3 will be shared across cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Multi-core_chips).

In the program in the question, one thread is accessing each of these
global variables:

```
unsigned long long OddSum = 0;
unsigned long long EvenSum = 0;
```

A typical C++ compiler will put these two variables next to each other
in memory.  That means they are likely to share a
[cache line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_entries),
meaning that if one variable is loaded into the L1 cache of one core,
then both are in that same core's L1.  But a given cache line cannot be
in both cores' caches at the same time, since then the computation would
become inconsistent due to having two copies of each variable.  (Note
that the precise notion of consistency depends on the
[memory ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering)
guarantees provided by the processor architecture.)

When thread 1 (T1) starts, it pulls the cache line containing both
variables into its cache.  When thread 2 (T2) begins executing, it needs
them, so the cache coherence protocol engages, forcibly evicting the
data from the T1 cache.  Approximately one nanosecond later, T1 once
again needs the data, so again coherence kicks in, and the data is
evicted from T2's cache.  The two cores fight over the cache line
containing the data elements continuously for the entire computation,
and all that fighting is potentially much slower than letting one core
do all of the work.

On my system (cygwin g++ 11.4.0 on Windows 10, 4-core i5-6600K CPU @
3.50GHz, median of 5 measurements, +/- is interquartile), with no
compiler optimizations, I measure:

- Original program, single thread: 6489 ms +/- 28 ms
- Original program, two threads: 6836 ms +/- 694 ms

The threaded version is not that much slower, but it's definitely not
faster, and the high dispersion is also a consequence of the cache
coherence mechanism being unhappy.

### Solution: Separating the data

We can fix the coherence problem by moving the two variables far enough
apart that they do not share a cache line.  Then the variables needed
by each core can live in their respective L1s without interference.

To separate the variables, as a proof of concept, it is often sufficient
to declare another variable in between:

```
unsigned long long OddSum = 0;
char separation[32];          // <---- added
unsigned long long EvenSum = 0;
```

To confirm this solves the problem, here are the measurements:

- 32 bytes separation, single thread: 6455 ms +/- 28 ms
- 32 bytes separation, two threads: 3276 ms +/- 22 ms

On my system, less than 32 bytes of separation is not enough.  By
printing out the addresses of `OddSum` and `EvenSum`, I can see that 32
bytes of separation causes the variables to be placed by the compiler 64
bytes apart.  Since (in my case) `OddSum` is page-aligned, that means my
cache line size is 64 bytes.  (Under Linux, that value is also visible
in `/proc/cpuinfo`.)

### Red herring: Enabling compiler optimizations

Now let's return to the original program and add compiler optimizations:

- Original program, single thread, -O2: 2164 ms +/- 26 ms
- Original program, two threads, -O2: 1340 ms +/- 60 ms

It looks like this solved the problem, right?  But what did the
optimizer actually do?  Let's look at the output of
`objdump --disassemble` applied to the object file, specifically
the `findEven` function:

```
0000000000000000 <_Z8findEvenyy>:
   0:   48 39 d1                cmp    %rdx,%rcx
   3:   77 2e                   ja     33 <_Z8findEvenyy+0x33>
   5:   48 8b 05 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0(%rip),%rax        # c <_Z8findEvenyy+0xc>
   c:   45 31 c0                xor    %r8d,%r8d
   f:   90                      nop
  10:   f6 c1 01                test   $0x1,%cl
  13:   75 09                   jne    1e <_Z8findEvenyy+0x1e>
  15:   48 01 c8                add    %rcx,%rax
  18:   41 b8 01 00 00 00       mov    $0x1,%r8d
  1e:   48 83 c1 01             add    $0x1,%rcx
  22:   48 39 ca                cmp    %rcx,%rdx
  25:   73 e9                   jae    10 <_Z8findEvenyy+0x10>
  27:   45 84 c0                test   %r8b,%r8b
  2a:   74 07                   je     33 <_Z8findEvenyy+0x33>
  2c:   48 89 05 00 00 00 00    mov    %rax,0x0(%rip)        # 33 <_Z8findEvenyy+0x33>
  33:   c3                      ret
  34:   66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data16 cs nopw 0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  3b:   00 00 00 00 
  3f:   90                      nop
```

The loop goes from address `10` (the first `test`) to address `25`
(`jae`).  The key observation is there are *no memory accesses* in the
loop body!  The value of `EvenSum` is read by the instruction at `5`,
then written at `2c`, but only if the `if` statement was executed
(instruction `18` sets a flag that is checked by instruction `27`).

In contrast, this is the disassembly without optimization:

```
0000000000000000 <_Z8findEvenyy>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
   8:   48 89 4d 10             mov    %rcx,0x10(%rbp)
   c:   48 89 55 18             mov    %rdx,0x18(%rbp)
  10:   48 8b 45 10             mov    0x10(%rbp),%rax
  14:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  18:   eb 26                   jmp    40 <_Z8findEvenyy+0x40>
  1a:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  1e:   83 e0 01                and    $0x1,%eax
  21:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  24:   75 15                   jne    3b <_Z8findEvenyy+0x3b>
  26:   48 8b 15 08 00 00 00    mov    0x8(%rip),%rdx        # 35 <_Z8findEvenyy+0x35>
  2d:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  31:   48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax
  34:   48 89 05 08 00 00 00    mov    %rax,0x8(%rip)        # 43 <_Z8findEvenyy+0x43>
  3b:   48 83 45 f8 01          addq   $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
  40:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  44:   48 3b 45 18             cmp    0x18(%rbp),%rax
  48:   76 d0                   jbe    1a <_Z8findEvenyy+0x1a>
  4a:   90                      nop
  4b:   90                      nop
  4c:   48 83 c4 10             add    $0x10,%rsp
  50:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  51:   c3                      ret
```

This time the loop goes from `1a` to `48`.  Instruction `26` reads the
value of `EvenSum` from memory into a register, and instruction `34`
writes the result of the addition back to `EvenSum` in memory.  This is
the memory traffic that collides with the traffic from the other thread.

So why do I call enabling optimization a red herring?  Because it's only
a temporary fix, for this particular definition of `findEven`.  The
function is *currently* so simple that the compiler sees it can avoid
all memory traffic in the loop, so lifts that out.  But as soon as you
do something more realistically complicated, the memory accesses in the
loop will return, and performance will take a big hit once again.

### Concluding thoughts

Diagnosing and fixing performance problems in multithreaded code is
difficult.  I just guessed what the problem was and confirmed it with
the disassembly and experimentation.  The "solution" I've proposed above
is obviously fragile: if my CPU had a cache line of 128 bytes instead of
64 bytes then more separation would be needed.  And if the compiler
decided to put the `separation` variable elsewhere, or discard it
entirely, then that too would break things.

To reliably detect when caching issues are the cause of slow performance,
you can use a profiler that can use
[hardware performance counters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_performance_counter).
That would show the high coherence eviction count associated with the
memory instructions in this example.  But such profilers are, in my
experience, fairly difficult to use (which is why I didn't in this
case).

To reliably avoid coherence problems in particular, try to design your
program in such a way that you can put all the data used by each thread
physically together, ideally on separate *pages* of memory (a page is
typically 8 or 16 kiB) from that used by other threads.  (Low-level
allocation routines such as `mmap` or `VirtualAlloc` can allocate at the
page granularity.)